# speedup multiple condition query in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, query-optimization, pymongo

I have a big dataset(~50G) while each document is structured as follows.

```
{
   'docid':0x12345,
   'text':'this is a text example',
    'datetime':datetime.datetime(2012,12,1,12,00,00),
}
```

And I would like to query the documents which match some words in 'text' field and the 'datetime' in a time span.

So I create the index for both 'text' and 'datetime' fields, and run the query as :

```
db.test.find({"$text":{"$search":"canon"},'datetime': {'$gte': start, '$lt': end}},{"score":{"$meta":"textScore"}})
```

But I find the query is very very slow and I do not know when I can have the result.

Anything wrong? and how to speedup the query?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things to note:
1. You do not need both single and double quotes around the word canon (*'"canon"'*). Just "canon" should suffice.
2. is "*takentime*" a key in your documents?  or did you mean datetime? Entering a key that doesn't exist will slow the query tremendously as it causes mongodb to search the whole collection

Comment: Yes, they are some typos in my question. thanks for your carefulness.

Comment: you are welcome. MongoDB can be tricky in the sense that it doesn't error out when you have a typo in the field name